# How to integrate dynamically JS code in success page in magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento, zend-framework

I know that success.phtml is the file where I should put the code I want to execute, but I received from CJ this file which is not an html, its a php class.

Question is very simple: I would like to know how can I integrate this file into the success.phtml after an order has been received.?

Thank you

```
class CommissionJunction extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
{

    /**
     * Get SKU, quantity, price and discount amount for each product in a given order
     * @param object $order
     * @return array
     */
    private function _getOrderProductsList($order) {
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
        $purchasedSkus = array();
        $count_orderItems = count($orderItems);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count_orderItems; $i++) {
            $purchasedSkus[$i] = array(
              'ITEM' => $orderItems[$i]['sku'],
                'QTY' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['qty_ordered'],0), // no decimals
                'AMT' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['price'],2) // 2 decimal places
                'DCNT' => number_format(abs($orderItems[$i]['discount_amount']),2) */
            );
        }
        return $purchasedSkus;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Universal Data (JSON) Object for Commission Junction.
     * This object contains the order details passed on to Commission Junction for reporting purposes
     * on the Checkout Success / Order Confirmation page.
     * Notes:
     *  - CID, TYPE AND CURRENCY are hard coded
     * @param string $orderId
     * @return JSON object Universal Data Object for Commission Junction $json_masterTmsUdp
     */
    public function getCommissionJunctionUdo($orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
        $udo = array();
        $udo['CID'] = 'XXXX';
        $udo['TYPE'] = 'XXXX';
        $udo['CURRENCY'] = 'USD';
        $udo['OID'] = $orderId;
        $udo['DISCOUNT'] = number_format(abs($order->discount_amount),2);

        $order_coupon_code = $order->coupon_code;
        if(!is_null($order_coupon_code) && !empty($order_coupon_code)) {
            $udo['COUPON'] = $order_coupon_code;
        }

        $udo['PRODUCTLIST'] = self::_getOrderProductsList($order);       

        if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('aff_commissionjunction') == 'cjafflx') {
            $udo['FIRECJ'] = "TRUE";
        }
        else {
            $udo['FIRECJ'] = "FALSE";
        }

        $masterTmsUdo['CJ'] = $udo;
        $json_masterTmsUdo = json_encode($masterTmsUdo);

        return $json_masterTmsUdo;

    }



}
```

JS File template

```
<script> var MasterTmsUdo = { 'CJ' : { 'CID': '123', 'TYPE': '123', 'DISCOUNT' : '5.00', 'OID': 'SAMPLE_OID', 'CURRENCY' : 'USD', 'COUPON' : 'SAVE20', 'FIRECJ' : 'xxxx', PRODUCTLIST : [ { 'ITEM' : 'ABC', 'AMT' : '1.00', 'QTY' : '3' }, { 'ITEM' : 'ABC', 'AMT' : '5.00', 'QTY' : '1' } ] } }; </script>
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with JavaScript - as you say, that's PHP code.

Comment: hold on, I will edit.

Comment: CJ gave me the php code that generates the JS code, and they provided me how the JS will look like too (see JS Template), the question is how can I integrate the PHP to generate that JS code, on the sucess.phtml (head) from magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bad way of solving this, but from what I can deduce, they want you to do something like this at the top of `success.phtml`:

```
<?php require_once "path/to/commissionjunction.php" ?>
<script>var MasterTmsUdo = <?php echo CommissionJunction::getCommissionJunctionUdo($this->getOrderId()); ?></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

I just realized that's a helper class. Assuming the module is properly configured with config.xml and having that file in the `Helper` dir, this should work--without a `require_once` like my original example.

```
<script>var MasterTmsUdo = <?php echo Mage::helper('commissionjunction')->getCommissionJunctionUdo($this->getOrderId()); ?></script>
```

Comment: where is the best place to put the php file?, magento structure its so complicated :)

Comment: I realized they meant that file to be a Magento Helper class and updated my answer. Is that the only file they provided you? Did they give you any sort of directory structure with it?

Comment: no, they did not give me any structure, can you please tell me where should I put it?

Comment: Because that is all they've given you, you can just drop it in the `lib` directory, and go with my first example. A better way would be to properly set up the module, but I would have expected CommissionJunction to do that...

Comment: Also note that in the file you provided there are a few errors: needs an opening `<?php` at the top, and it either needs a comma at the end of the `'AMT'` line or an opening /* on the `'DCNT'` line.

Comment: maybe u can help me with this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221090/how-to-add-a-js-on-the-head-for-all-files-but-differently-for-the-success-page

Comment: what about if I need it in the head tag of only the success page?

Comment: To me, it would only make sense to put static sources in the head tag. The contents of this `<script>` tag are very much dynamic, as `getCommissionJunctionUdo()` is returning JSON specific to the current order.