# How to add a JS on the head for all files, but differently for the success page in magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have the following requirement.

Add the following JS on the head tag element of all magento pages.
I did this through magento, system configuration, design, head, miscellaneous scripts.

```
<script>/*DO NOT ALTER *** tt*/(function(e){var t="1340",n=document,r,i,s={http:"http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js",https:"https://secure-cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js"},o=s[/\w+/.exec(window.location.protocol)[0]];i=n.createElement("script"),i.type="text/javascript",i.async=!0,i.src=o+"#"+t,r=n.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],r.parentNode.insertBefore(i,r),i.readyState?i.onreadystatechange=function(){if(i.readyState==="loaded"||i.readyState==="complete")i.onreadystatechange=null}:i.onload=function(){try{e()}catch(t){}}})(function(){});</script>
```

No big deal so far

**2nd. Add the following JS on the success page, (also on the head element)**

```
 //TOP OF HEAD TAG, DIRECTLY AFTER JQUERY 
<script> 
var MasterTmsUdo = { 'CJ' : { 'CID': '1531288', 'TYPE': '373626', 'DISCOUNT' : '5.00', 'OID': 'SAMPLE_OID', 'CURRENCY' : 'USD', 'COUPON' : 'SAVE20', 'FIRECJ' : 'xxxx', PRODUCTLIST : [ { 'ITEM' : 'ABC', 'AMT' : '1.00', 'QTY' : '3' }, { 'ITEM' : 'ABC', 'AMT' : '5.00', 'QTY' : '1' } ] } }; 
</script> 
<script> 
//THE CJ AFFILIATE JAVASCRIPT SHOULD GO HERE, BELOW THE UDO BUT ABOVE OTHER SCRIPTS (see above)
</script>
```

I got help from another thread in how to generate the JSON objects dinamically: 
[How to integrate dynamically JS code in success page in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219799/how-to-integrate-dinamically-js-code-in-success-page-in-magento/25219918?noredirect=1#comment39282382_25219918)

However, they explicitly say, that this last code should be only on the success page, if I add that code in succcess.phtml then it wouldnt render in the HEAD tag of the success page I suppose.  If I add it in header.phtml, then it would render in all pages and not only in success.phtml

any idea?

Comment: If the data is hardcoded you could do it via some Javascript. (But I wouldnt suggest it!! Only if nothing else comes up) I dont know magento templating very well, so cant help here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize that this doesn't directly answer your question, but it does provide a solution:

There's no technical reason any of this needs to be in the `<head>`, and I'm unsure of a good way to bring that dynamically generated JS into the head.

The requirement I do see is that MasterTmsUdo needs to be set before your CJ affiliate javascript. So you may be better off just including the CJ affiliate javascript at the very end of the page (so it will be loaded *after* your `success.phtml`), just above the `</body>`, which you can do like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <action method="addJs"><script>commissionjunction/cj.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

where `siteroot/js/commissionjunction/cj.js` contains

```
/*DO NOT ALTER *** tt*/(function(e){var t="1340",n=document,r,i,s={http:"http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js",https:"https://secure-cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js"},o=s[/\w+/.exec(window.location.protocol)[0]];i=n.createElement("script"),i.type="text/javascript",i.async=!0,i.src=o+"#"+t,r=n.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],r.parentNode.insertBefore(i,r),i.readyState?i.onreadystatechange=function(){if(i.readyState==="loaded"||i.readyState==="complete")i.onreadystatechange=null}:i.onload=function(){try{e()}catch(t){}}})(function(){});
```